# Deconstruction of Javascript objects in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
var myArrayOfObjects = [
                {Attempt: 1, level: 8, Score: 10},
                {Attempt: 2, level: 9, Score: 8},
                {Attempt: 3, level: 3, Score: 7},
                {Attempt: 4, level: 4, Score: 9},
                {Attempt: 5, level: 3, Score: 5},
                {Attempt: 6, level: 1, Score: 8}];


  console.log(myArrayOfObjects);
```

Attempts can be infinite. Both Levels and Scores are numbers ranging from 1 to 10. But in this problem, scores are irrelevant for me.

What I am trying to figure out, is the (best) way to log for each attempt, whether a level has been tried before, the levels tried below and the levels tried above.

Therefore my desired output would be:

```
//[{Attempt: 1, At this level: 0, Above this level: 0, Below this level: 0}; 
//{Attempt: 2, At this level: 0, Above this level: 0, Below this level: 1}; 
//{Attempt: 3, At this level: 0, Above this level: 2, Below this level: 0};
//{Attempt: 4, At this level: 0, Above this level: 2, Below this level: 1};
//{Attempt: 5, At this level: 1, Above this level: 3, Below this level: 0};
//{Attempt: 6, At this level: 0, Above this level: 5, Below this level: 0}];
```

Any ideas of how I can achieve this using pure Javascript?

Comment: What is a `level above / below`? Is your `myArrayOfObjects` one level?

Comment: Eventually it would be array per user with other levels.

Comment: where do you get the missing data from?

Comment: Btw why is the title called "Deconstruction"? Isn't this more like a: "How to **construct**" ?

Comment: I want to strip or dismantle my problem and then reconstruct it. Therefore for me, 'deconstruction' is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop and an array that tracks the number of attempts per level will do:

```
function sum(arr) { return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); }

let attempts = [];
for (const [index, obj] of myArrayOfObjects.entries()) {
    console.assert(index + 1 == obj.Attempt); // ensure input is sorted by attempt
    console.log(`Attempt ${obj.Attempt},
    At this level: ${attempts[obj.level] || 0},
    Above this level: ${sum(attempts.slice(obj.level+1))},
    Below this level: ${sum(attempts.slice(0, obj.level))}`); 
    attempts[obj.level] = (attempts[obj.level] || 0) + 1; // increase count for this level
}
```

You can also put the results in new objects and those in an array.

Comment: Could you give me a reference to `console.log("Text ${variable}")` never seen this before

Comment: Thank you very much Bergi. This is a great solution.

Comment: @Elias It's a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but doesn't really matter for the grain of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at his code. It may or may not help you :)

```js
var levels = [];

// Create attemp like cerateAttempt(levelNumber, score)
createAttempt(0, 10);
createAttempt(0, 13);
createAttempt(0, 14);
createAttempt(0, 15);

// Log all attempts for lvl 0
for(let i = 0; i < levels[0].attempts.length; i++) {
  console.log("-------------------")
  console.log("Attempt: " + i)
  console.log("Score: " + levels[0].attempts[i].score);
  if(!levels[0].attempts[i + 1]) console.log("Score after: None -> last score")
  else console.log("Score after: " + levels[0].attempts[i + 1].score);
  if(!levels[0].attempts[i - 1]) console.log("Score before: None -> first score");
  else console.log("Score before: " + levels[0].attempts[i - 1].score); 
}

function createAttempt(lvl, score) {
  if(typeof(levels[lvl]) == "undefined") {
    levels[lvl] = {};
    levels[lvl].attempts = [];
  }
  levels[lvl].attempts.push({score: score});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TerenceE.Uttley Please take a quick glimpse at that code :)